# Randomized control trials with budget

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset containing a list of randomized control trials with their budget.

I am aware of https://clinicaltrials.gov and [Cochrane Central Register of Controlled Trials (CENTRAL)](http://www.cochranelibrary.com/about/central-landing-page.html) but the budget isn't mentioned (perhaps it is for some exceptions?).